# How to add a namespace without a prefix into a SOAP request method tag using SAAJ?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, saaj

I am trying to assemble a SOAP request using SAAJ.

The original SOAP request looks like this

```
(...)
<soapenv:Body>
 <methodName xmlns="http://xyz.abc/asdfgh">
   (...)
 </methodName>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Using SAAJ, my code would look like

```
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement req= soapBody.addChildElement("methodName");
req.addNamespaceDeclaration("", "http://xyz.abc/asdfgh");
```

The problem, of course, is that the namespace prefix can't be empty or null.

So how can I generate the SOAP request namespace without a prefix in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the `methodName` element with a ***default namespace***, change

```
SOAPElement req= soapBody.addChildElement("methodName");
```

to

```
SOAPElement req= soapBody.addChildElement("methodName","","http://xyz.abc/asdfgh");
```